# Python List View - get and group data for table by same user and date

Tags: python, database, listview

**Hi. I am working on web app and I am trying to code a List View for getting data from database to create a table for statistics.**

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('user'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

I have a object called **Activity** where is '**user**' as *ForeignKey* and '**created**' as *DateTimeField*.

**Here you can see my code of List View:**

```
class ActivityCountListView(LoginPermissionRequiredMixin, DisplayListViewMixin, SortingListViewMixin, ListView,):
model = Activity
permission_required = 'directory.list_activity'
displays = ['list', 'table']
paginate_values = [10, 50, 100]
paginate_by_display = {'table': paginate_values, 'list': paginate_values}
sorting_options = {'-created': _('Newest'), 'created': _('Oldest'), '-modified': _("Recently modified")}

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.filter.qs.select_related('user')
    return self.sort_queryset(queryset)

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.filter = ActivityFilter(request.user, request.GET, queryset=self.get_whole_queryset())
    return super(ActivityCountListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_whole_queryset(self):
    return Activity.objects.restrict_user(self.request.user)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context_data = super(ActivityCountListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context_data['filter'] = self.filter

    activities = Activity.objects \
        .annotate(day=ExtractDay('created'), month=ExtractMonth('created'), year=ExtractYear('created'))\
        .values('user', 'day', 'month', 'year') \
        .order_by('user')\

    data = self.get_data(activities)

    context_data.update({
        'data': data
    })

    return context_data

def get_data(self, activities):
    data = {}



    for activities_data in activities:
        print(activities_data)
        user = activities_data['user']
        day = activities_data['day']
        month = activities_data['month']
        year = activities_data['year']

        dt = datetime(year, month, day).date()
        formatted_date = str(dt)

        data.update({user: dict()})


        data[user][formatted_date] = 1


    print(data.keys())
    print(data.values())
    print(data)

    return data
```

**using this code I get print response like this:**

**print print(activities_data):**

```
{'user': 549, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
{'user': 350, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
{'user': 746, 'day': 31, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
{'user': 1, 'day': 31, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
{'user': 1, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
{'user': 1, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
{'user': 526, 'day': 31, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
{'user': 526, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
{'user': 109, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
{'user': 419, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
```

**print(data.keys()):**

```
dict_keys([549, 350, 746, 1, 526, 109, 419])
```

**print(data.values()):**

```
dict_values([{'2018-07-24': 1}, {'2018-07-24': 1}, {'2018-07-31': 1}, {'2018-07-24': 1}, {'2018-07-24': 1}, {'2018-07-24': 1}, {'2018-07-24': 1}])
```

**print(data):**

```
{549: {'2018-07-24': 1}, 350: {'2018-07-24': 1}, 746: {'2018-07-31': 1}, 1: {'2018-07-24': 1}, 526: {'2018-07-24': 1}, 109: {'2018-07-24': 1}, 419: {'2018-07-24': 1}}
```

... but **it's not** like I want to have because **for same user there is only one date and there is not count for activities**... I expect response like that:

```
{549: {'2018-07-24': 1}, 350: {'2018-07-24': 1}, 746: {'2018-07-31': 1}, 1: {'2018-07-24': 2, '2018-07-31': 1,}, 526: {'2018-07-24': 1, '2018-07-31: 1}, 109: {'2018-07-24': 1}, 419: {'2018-07-24': 1}}
```

***For better understanding:***
**If there is more than one activity for same user (like user id 1):**

```
{'user': 1, 'day': 31, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
{'user': 1, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
{'user': 1, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}
```

**I expect data response like this :**

```
1: {'2018-07-24': 2, '2018-07-31': 1,},
```

and **not** just like this:

```
1: {'2018-07-24': 1},
```

I really don't know how to do it. I would be so glad to you if you help me and write me what to change and what add to code.... **THANK YOU SO MUCH**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> activities_lst = [{'user': 549, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}, {'user': 350, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}, {'user': 746, 'day': 31, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}, {'user': 1, 'day': 31, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}, {'user': 1, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}, {'user': 1, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}, {'user': 526, 'day': 31, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}, {'user': 526, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}, {'user': 109, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}, {'user': 419, 'day': 24, 'month': 7, 'year': 2018}]
>>>
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> f = lambda x: x['user']
>>> res = {user:['{year}-{month:02}-{day}'.format(**date) for date in date_lst] for user,date_lst in groupby(sorted(activities_lst, key=f), f)}
>>> res = {user:{date:len(list(v)) for date,v in groupby(date_lst)} for user,date_lst in res.items()}
>>> 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(res)
{1: {'2018-07-24': 2, '2018-07-31': 1},
 109: {'2018-07-24': 1},
 350: {'2018-07-24': 1},
 419: {'2018-07-24': 1},
 526: {'2018-07-24': 1, '2018-07-31': 1},
 549: {'2018-07-24': 1},
 746: {'2018-07-31': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem is in get_data() call.

in place of this

```
data[user][formatted_date] = 1
```

may be need to write as below

```
if formatted_date in data[user]:
   data[user][formatted_date] += 1
else
   data[user][formatted_date] = 1
```